# Is there a document tool for python?

Tags: python

Like perldoc for perl, man for c.

Is there one for python?

Comment: The answer to "Is there an X for python?" is always "No. There are innumerable." :)

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking for documentation for standard modules etc, or are you looking for a tool to generate documentation for your own stuff?

Answer (score 6):

Normally, you should use [documentation strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#documentation-strings):

```
def foo(bar):
   """ Applies the foo operation onto bar """
   # ...
```

You can then generate HTML (or other output formats) with [pydoc](http://docs.python.org/library/pydoc.html) or [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/), or use the built-in [`help`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help) function to see them on live objects.

The documentation of the built-in modules is [available online](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html) ([also downloadable](http://docs.python.org/download.html)) or via `help`.

Answer (score 4):

There is - its called: "pydoc". You can run it from shell, for example:

```
$ pydoc sys
```

will give you help about sys module. It can export help to html (pydoc -w) or spawn server with simple gui management:

```
$ pydoc -g
```

Answer (score 3):

In the python shell, you can use the [help](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help) built-in function (for example, here's the documentation of the os.path module):

```
>>> import os
>>> help(os.path)
```

> Help on module posixpath:
>
> NAME
>       posixpath - Common operations on Posix pathnames.
>
> FILE
>       /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
>
> MODULE DOCS
>       http://docs.python.org/library/posixpath
>
> DESCRIPTION
>       Instead of importing this module directly, import os and refer to
>       this module as os.path.  The "os.path" name is an alias for this
>       module on Posix systems; on other systems (e.g. Mac, Windows),
>       os.path provides the same operations in a manner specific to that
>       platform, and is an alias to another module (e.g. macpath, ntpath).
>
> ```
> Some of this can actually be useful on non-Posix systems too, e.g.
> for manipulation of the pathname component of URLs.
> ```
>
> FUNCTIONS
>
> ... ... ..